# Access HttpRequestMessage outside Controller Context

Tags: asp.net-web-api, autofac

Is it possible to access the current request information (HttpRequestMessage) outside of the context of a controller?

I would like to setup a tenant strategy (ITenantIdentificationStrategy) that involves the incoming request headers. In self hosted mode HttpContext.Current is not an option and I haven't found any other solutions.

Comment: this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013885/autofac-multi-tenant-ioc-container-in-an-asp-net-web-api-application

Comment: You are definitely looking for the @travis' answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14017242/463785

Comment: didn't I just link to it? :)

Comment: that solution does not work in self hosted mode, only web hosted??

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a HttpMessageHandler is what you are looking for.  MessageHandlers allow you to perform some kind of processing on every request and provides full access to the request and response message.